# Azure Notification Hub and Apple APNS Push Notifications unregistering devices

Tags: xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services

I am currently working on an application built in VS using a Xamarin Unified IOS project. one requirement of the application is the utilisation of push notifications. The issue is that our test device/application registers in the first instance without any issues, we can see the registration events in azure portals, and the azure service bus. I have also confirmed the initial registration using the 'Service Bus Explorer' application and the server explorer feature in VS.

The issue arises when sending the test push notification. According to all the logs I have access too the message is successfully pushed to apples APNS server and I can't see any failures being returned as part of the PNS request. However once this completed the device registration is removed and the notification never arrives on the test device.

My understanding is that the azure application hub handles PNS rejections itself in order to tidy up device registrations. This in and of itself is not a terrible idea, but due to a lack of logging, it's very hard to determine the root cause. I have done a ridiculous amount of googling for this one, and a lot of people suggest an issue with the apple certificates that are used. I have deleted, recreated, resigned, verified, both APNS certs and Provisioning profiles until I ran out of combinations. None of that has resolved the issue.

To make the issue more confusing, if I use a service such as 'http://pushtry.com' or 'http://pushwatch.com' and upload the certificate and device token, it will allow me to successfully push a notification to the device.

Am I missing something glaringly obvious? or is the notification hub absurdly difficult to setup and debug for APNS?

Any help you can provide will be appreciated, I would publish some code, but as I know that the device registers the correct device token, I don't see it necessary at this point, but please feel free to tell me otherwise. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many man hours and through luck rather than any kind of logical process, we determined that 'Azure Notification Hubs' have an in built validator for the apple device token that's passed up to the APNS. So even though there are multiple examples and answers out there that suggest submitting a device token without spaces or symbols to the notification hub, this is in fact the wrong approach. The device token should always be submitted to the 'Azure Notification Hub' in an 'as is' state, without any validating from within the Xamarin.IOS application. Although this seems like such a simple thing to overlook, there is a lot of contradictory evidence out there on google, and Azure's documentation says very little about the format of submitted device tokens. Anyway hopefully this will help someone else someday.

-- Edit --

Device Token format from Apple: < XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX >

Format that many online resources suggest it is passed to the notification hub as: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
without spaces or the '<' and '>'

However it should be passed through to the notification hub as it is received from Apple.

Comment: Hi, I work on the Notification Hubs team. We do NOT validate handle and do pass it along as is.
Your issue sounds more oriented around the production/development usage. Each hub can be declared prod or dev, and knows how to communicate to either the prod or dev endpoint at apns. The following combination should work:
1. prod/test unified apns cert, prod provisioning profile, prod hub
2. prod/test unified apns cert, dev provisioning profile, dev hub

Can you confirm that neither worked?

Comment: Hubs delete registrations after apns returns an invalid token/expired token error, meaning, if a dev device token is passed to prod apns endpoint, the endpoint will reject it and result in device deletion. Same vice versa.

Comment: All very aware as you presumably can ascertain from my original post, however that being said the above answer is exactly the scenario that lead to being able to successfully send the test notification and solve the issue with the Azure notification hub from unregistering the device.

Comment: Hi all, I am trying device token registering in hub in 'as is' state but getting same response from notification hub. It remove's the registrations from notification hub when I send test notifications.

Answer (score 2):

What's also important to note, if you are using Azure Notification Hubs APNS, is that it will unregister devices if the application mode is not set to in production. Once you have deployed to the app store, you need to switch the "application mode" in your Azure Notification Hub from sandbox to production. Otherwise your device registrations will be unregistered.

[image]

I'm using the same token/key for both sandbox and production with no issues.

[image]